# Display message with Lua

Tags: user-interface, lua, output, display

I am making a simple idea generator with Lua and I want it to display a error/notification with the output.
Something a little like this:

[image: 1]

I've tried looking at other posts on stack overflow but the code was too advanced for me to understand.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: What kind of notification do you want to show?  A simple OS-native MessageBox?   A MessageBox inside a game?  A standard balloon notification integrated into OS desktop environment?

Comment: Please note this is impossible in Lua without 3rd-party libraries.

Comment: @AlgoRythm, it may be possible by calling an external program with `os.execute` or `io.popen`.

Comment: @lhf well, that's just cheating

Answer (score 0):

[fltk4lua](https://github.com/siffiejoe/lua-fltk4lua) is easy for simple stuff like that, yea.

```
#! /usr/bin/env lua
--  sudo apt install libfltk1.3-dev
--  luarocks install fltk4lua

local fl = require( 'fltk4lua' )
fl .scheme( 'gtk+' )

local Width, Height = 300, 200
local Title = 'Lua Output'
local window = fl .Window( Width, Height, Title )

local icon = fl .Chart{ Width *0.1,  Height *0.1,  100,  100,  type = FL_BAR_CHART }
local text = fl .Box{ Width *0.5,  Height *0.3,  100,  30,  'Hello World!' }
local button = fl .Button{ Width *0.5,  Height *0.75,  100,  30,  'Okay' }

icon :add( 6,  6,  0x05 )  --   www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/drawing.html#drawing_colors
icon :add( 5,  5,  0x04 )
icon :add( 4,  4,  0x02 )
icon :add( 3,  3,  0x01 )

window :end_group()
window :show( arg )
fl .run()
```

Comment: When I Run it with the lua-fltk4lua-master in my workspace and the code at the bottom of my script, it says "Exception has occurred: module 'fltk4lua' not found:" How do I fix this?

Comment: `-master` implies you cloned it from GitHub.  I wrote install instructions in there `luarocks install fltk4lua`, but you decided to do it a different way.  Either use luarocks, or learn how to compile it from that repo clone.

Comment: I'm confused, what do I need to put in workspace and how do I do get luarocks?